# prove that $F(x,y ) = F(x + a y)$ for some $a \in F$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field with $ x, y $ algebraic and separable over $F$. Does there exist a element $a \in F$ such that $ F(x,y) = F (x + ay )$ when $ |F| < \infty $?

---

I proved this is true when $|F| = \infty$. But I can't prove the finite case or give a counterexample. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by $F(x)$ and $F(x, y)$? Are these the polynomials in one and two variables with coefficients in $F$? Also, could you show your proof of what you do have, even in the case $|F| < \infty$.

Comment: Pretty sure from context $F(x)$ is the smallest field containing $F$ and the element $x$, $F(x, y)$ the smallest field containing $F$ and the elements $x, y$, etc., right?

Comment: @grantfgates Yes, I think that's very clear.